# Location manager not working, semaphore error, delegates not being called, why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gps, automatic-ref-counting, core-location

I believe I have read and followed most of the tutorials on how to receive location updates for the user. I have a class (UserTracker) which imports CoreLocation and implements the correct delegate protocol. I've also implemented the correct methods. The problem is that when I test the class with this method:

```
-(bool)test
{
    UserTracker * ut = [[UserTracker alloc] init];
    [ut startTracking]; 

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:30];

    [ut stopTracking];

    NSLog(@"Accumulated distance is %f m", [pt sumDist]);

    return true;
}
```

I receive the follow error:

```
libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_semaphore_signal:
0x1e07e02:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x1e07e06:  movl   $1, %ecx
0x1e07e0b:  lock                         Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x20)
0x1e07e0c:  xaddl  %ecx, 32(%eax)
0x1e07e10:  incl   %ecx
0x1e07e11:  testl  %ecx, %ecx
0x1e07e13:  jg     0x1e07e22                 ; dispatch_semaphore_signal + 32
0x1e07e15:  cmpl   $2147483648, %ecx
0x1e07e1b:  je     0x1e07e25                 ; dispatch_semaphore_signal + 35
0x1e07e1d:  jmp    0x1e081c1                 ; _dispatch_semaphore_signal_slow
0x1e07e22:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x1e07e24:  ret    
0x1e07e25:  ud2
```

Both are run on the same thread by the way (is this a problem?).

Some methods from UserTrack.m:

```
-(void)startTracking
{
    if(_isTracking)
        return;
    // Clear old data
    [_locations removeAllObjects];
    [_lm startUpdatingLocation];
    _isTracking = true;
    NSLog(@"is tracking!");
}

// Stop tracking GPS coordinates
-(void)stopTracking
{
    if (!_isTracking)
        return;
    if(_lm != nil)
        [_lm stopUpdatingLocation];
    _isTracking = false;
    NSLog(@"STOPPED TRACKING");
}

-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        _isTracking = false;
        _locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _lm.delegate = self;
        _lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
        _lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Also implemented in the same class:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
// Callback: new GPS coordinate available
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

which are not being called... Is this a thread problem? Why am I getting this strange semaphore error?

Comment: Why are you calling [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:30]? Also, did you set the delegate?

Comment: So that I have time to input simulated coordinates by hand using the simulator. When the coordinates are inputed, the program should call the callbacks which record them and when all is finished a distance calculation is being made... delegate is set in init-method.

Comment: Did you know that the simulator provides coordinates? You just have to turn them on. I suggest trying that to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: What is the difference whether I provide coordinates manually by clicking the arrow-button in the simulator or it doing it by reading a coordinate file?

Comment: My point is that sleeping your thread might be causing your problem. Assuming you set the delegate correctly there is no reason for the delegate methods not to be called. Sleeping the thread probably prevents that.

Comment: ok, but isn't a better solution to run the location service on the background thread?

Comment: No, the better solution is to follow the examples on the developer site. Take out the sleep. Don't stop the tracking. See if the delegate methods get called. Then you can worry about your coordinates.

Comment: Removed everything but somehow they aren't being called... Maybe the program terminates before they are called?

Comment: Are you sure you set your delegate? Not just implemented the methods, but actually told the location manager what your delegate is?

Comment: I have:  _lm.delegate = self;     in init()

Comment: Are you sure that _lm is a valid object when you call your startTracking method?

Comment: What you mean with valid object? if it was e.g. nil I should have gotten exception?

Comment: From the docs: In Objective-C, it is valid to send a message to nil—it simply has no effect at runtime. Step through with the debugger or log the object.

Comment: It seems to be a valid NSObject, isa CLLocationManager...

Comment: As a general rule, putting a sleep in code is usually the wront path ...

Comment: It is valid when you call startTracking? Obviously there is something very simple going wrong if you cannot get it to call the delegate methods. Are you sure the simulator is providing coordinates? You turned it on in the simulator right? Debug -> Location ->

Comment: yes, I even have my own custom locations... From my programming experience I feel that something is perhaps terminating before call can be made... I don't know...

Comment: Could be that you are allocating UserTracker and then returning false right away.

Comment: Perhaps, but how do I then test the location functionality properly? I need to construct a test-method which tests the location manager and then returns... how can this be done using the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location manager class was tested here:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // TODO: remove this class
        BPTest * bt = [[BPTest alloc] init];
        [bt runTests];
        // Above must be removed and the location test inserted directly here...

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([BPAppDelegate class]));    
    }
}
```

as a quick "hacky" way to test it... Only when I tried to move the test completly out of the "BPTest"-class and execute it directly before the call to "UIApplicationMain", only then the delegate methods seemed to get called...